# How Azure Data flow Actives run is run in sequence or parallel

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is data flow actives run in parallel or sequence. In more detail, the image we have two sources  named as Source1 and Source2 so when I run this pipeline will it run both sources together, or it executed source1, and when it all done to sink1 then it executes the sources2

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data Flow actives run  in sequence. When we run the Data flow, it executed source1, and when it all done to sink1 then it executes the sources2. You can find this in pipeline details.

For example, I create two actives in my pipeline Data Flow.

[image]

When we run the Data Flow, we can see the details from here.
[image]

Before the pipeline Data Flow actives running.
[image]

After the pipeline Data Flow actives running succeed:

[image]

The details become this: 
[image]

**My source1 data preview:**
[image]

**My source2 data preview:**
[image]

**Result in my table:**

[image]

Hope this helps.